# Ubuntu 18.04 does not load SSD NVMe XPG Gammix - Lenovo Gamer Legion Y530

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd, nvme

I have a Notebook Lenovo Gamer Legion Y530 I7-8750h, an SSD NVMe XPG Gammix 1TB and a SSD 1TB SATA installed.

The BIOS recognizes both drives.

[image]

I left set on BIOS to Boot Mode: Legacy Support

[image]

The problem is, when I boot the installation on Ubuntu 18.04 I got a `nvme0: failed to set APST feature (-19)` error. It recognizes the SSD, but not the NVMe (XPG S11).

[image]

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Why legacy if newer UEFI system? Almost all (even new) systems need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. Are drives set up as RAID or Intel SRT? You need to change to AHCI. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359208 &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: All controller mode are set to AHCI mode, instead of RST mode. I left set Legacy because of some articles I read. But I already tested UEFI, I got the same error.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware. Many say that resolves lots of issues.

Comment: @oldfred I updated only the bios, the SSD firmeware, the was no update, UEFI is it possible?

Comment: Several users in link to ubuntu forums installed to Y520. You newer system should be very similar. Also turn off UEFI fast boot. Make sure Windows fast startup is off also.

Comment: I did, same results. So sad... =/

Comment: Another possibility? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126456/wd-sandisk-nvme-m-2-stick-not-quite-working?rq=1 More info: https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization

Comment: @oldfred that's sounds good!
I did go to the edit menu from GRUB: https://ibb.co/mbVX80B e openned the editor: https://ibb.co/56KmYWB

Comment: @oldfred , my question is, it will be in this way? "... ro quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500 $vt-handoff" ?

Comment: I like to leave out quiet splash on test boots, so I can see process. Its just with new fast systems, it goes by very quick. If it stops you may see what was issue, but often not last line(s), but several further up.

Comment: @oldfred you saved my life! Worked! Really Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly sure what I suggested. Best if you post as an answer exactly what works and after a day you can accept that so others can find a good solution.