# Ubuntu 18.04 installer can't see Win10 SSD drive on ThinkPad E480

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, ssd, windows-10, thinkpad

I have ThinkPad E480 with Windows 10.
It has three default partitions:

- SSD:

  - 120GB with Windows 10
  - 355GB
- HDD:

  - 931BG

**My goal is to install Ubuntu on 355GB partition, but installer (and gparted) can't see this drive at all. How to do that?**

Ubuntu installer is able to see only HDD and pen drive.

In my BIOS settings:

- Main -> UEFI BIOS Version: **ROPET58W (1.35)**
- Config -> Storage -> Controller Mode: **AHCI mode**
- Security -> Secure Boot -> Secure Boot: **Disabled**

My SSD is **ADATA SX8200PNP**

Comment: Many SSD also need SSD firmware update and system probably needs UEFI update. Similar? https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201609-25122/  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161675/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-load-sdd-nvme-xpg-gammix-lenovo-gamer-legion-y530?noredirect=1#comment1935970_1161675

Comment: @oldfred I just updated UEFI to newest possible and still have this problem. I also tried passing nvme parameters to kernel during boot but without success.

Comment: If drive is NVMe have you also updated firmware for SSD?

Comment: @oldfred Actually I tried, but ADATA SSD ToolBox redirects me to XPG site where I can download PDF manual for this SSD -_-. So I'm not sure if there is any firmware update.

Comment: It says one of the options is SSD firmware update. That should tell you if you have latest version or not. https://www.adata.com/en/ss/software-6/

Comment: @oldfred Yes, exactly that was my hope. But it seems that they just give up this idea, and they redirect from firmware update to list of products.