# My linux disappear after instaling windows

Tags: windows, lenovo, gpt, mbr

Please, help me, I really need it. I have laptop Lenovo Legion y530H, it is quite problematic laptop for linux but I installed it with official guide.

```
Laptop has 1000Gb hdd and 256Gb ssd. 
I used 500Gb hdd + 100Gb ssd + 16Gb ssd for swap.
```

I wanted to use hdd for storing mediafiles and ssd for everything else. But I don't remember how ssd was mounted: as `/` or `/home`.

Everything worked excellent. But today I decided to install windows, downloaded iso, created boot usb, went to bios and set '`use efi first`' and set my usb at first position. When windows asked to choose a disk I tried to choose last 100gb on ssd but Windows could not to be installed there, so I chose 500gb hdd. But had error `windows can't be installed because this disk use mbr but windows need gpt`. So I opened terminal and executed

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0 (hdd)
clean
convert gpt
exit
```

Yes, it deleted all my files on hdd but they are not important. After that I installed windows on hdd, restarted laptop... and can't find ubuntu.

I really need your help because I have important data there. Which solutions are good for me:

1. recover old system <- the best solution
2. somehow upload important data to cloud, remove everything and reinstall linux again
   (windows doesn't matter)

I thought that second is possible with 'ubuntu test mode' so I created boot usb with the same version ubuntu (18.04lts) but after few seconds loading it just freeze. I don't know what to do. I tried two programs to create boot usb: mac balenaEther and mac uNetBootIn and formatted usb to mbr fat.

I hope somebody here know how to recover old linux after changing mbr to gpt.

P.S. When I try to load from boot usb I have next errors, then logo of ubuntu with loading which freeze after few seconds: [image]

Comment: Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. Now that Windows is UEFI, better to have Ubuntu in UEFI mode, but then you also should have gpt partitioning. If you installed in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode you may still be able to boot but boot drive? Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425907
Lenovo Gamer Legion Y530
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161675/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-load-sdd-nvme-xpg-gammix-lenovo-gamer-legion-y530?noredirect=1#comment1935970_1161675

Comment: I am sure on 90% that ubuntu was installed on 'legacy mode'. I don't understand your question "If you installed in BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode you may still be able to boot but boot drive? ". Now if I try to load from ubuntu boot usb - laptop freezes in both cases: in legacy mode and in efi-mode. And its scare me a little.. I tried even load windows it doesn't work too now. I tried to do it with windows boot usb and get error too... My laptop now is just peace of plastic and metal...

Comment: it can be issue with gpu drivers too. It is famous problem with that laptop. Could gpu drivers installed on windows affects on linux booting? Or it is just an issue with mbr/gpt?

Comment: Did your install of Windows convert drive to gpt, that would in effect erase Ubuntu  as it repartitioned drive, not converting from MBR to gpt. And even if converted, the UUIDs would all be different & Ubuntu would need a lot of updates for new UUIDs, grub & fstab at minimum. You have to have system set to boot in same mode you installed. If Windows is UEFI, UEFI boot mode & then select Windows entry from boot menu. IF BIOS you select a drive from UEFI boot menu. Default boot mode for installed system is separate from selection of boot mode on USB flash drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Boot_repair_after_a_Windows_Upgrade_on_Ubuntu_14.04_.28non-RAID.29

Comment: Also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: I think the easiest method mentioned in all of these is to use Bootrepair.

Comment: But you need to make a working iso to do that. Have you tried making the USB on Windows instead of mac? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Also, a common way to circumvent acpi errors is to use the "no mode set" option. Are you getting any screen before the errors or does it go straight to the errors?

Comment: The third thing, is there a way to set your SSD back to the first boot device in your BIOS settings? It sounds like, (aside from the USB errors) your boot device used to be your SSD and now it is your HDD. Switching your first boot device in your boot device order in your bios settings may fix unless grub was installed to hdd. As a last resort option, you could try unplugging your HDD and going from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a dual boot system, how does the BIOS choose which bootloader to run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981382/in-a-dual-boot-system-how-does-the-bios-choose-which-bootloader-to-run)

Comment: many thanks for response. All these solutions based on "linux try mode". But I couldn't even try it because it freeze on booting when ubuntu was logo showed. So I used windows live usb and ex2reader to export important files, erased all disks and reinstalled again