# Problems with Dual Booting my Lenovo legion y530

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to dual boot my legion y530. When I try to boot the bootable pendrive this error is coming up.

[image: The bios Error]

Ubuntu does boot up after that and installed correctly.
But after 3 days randomly ubuntu refused to boot up and stuck in the bootloop. I tried booting with nomodeset and other safe booting options but the result was the same. Now I uninstalled ubuntu and cleared the partition and I'm going to try again but still I'm getting the above boot error.
Any idea what might be causing it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15425/error-when-installing-unable-to-find-a-medium-containing-a-live-file-system

Comment: Many ACPI errors can be ignored. Have you updated UEFI from Lenovo for your system. And if SSD, updated SSD firmware? Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425907
Lenovo Gamer Legion Y530
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161675/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-load-sdd-nvme-xpg-gammix-lenovo-gamer-legion-y530?noredirect=1#comment1935970_1161675

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)