# GRUB disappeared!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 in my laptop which has UEFI.

Each time I change from Windows to Linux, I have to modify the EFI.

This time, I did it as usual and I faced to the grub disappeared.

The video can be downloaded from here: [WeTransfer link](https://we.tl/t-lwqowUH0GC)

**What do you recommend me to do?**

**[[ My first attempt ]]**

I followed the steps given in here: [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

My first attempt was to try the boot repair from ppa. I ran the boot repair and chose the option to "recommended repair". But, in the middle of the process I obtain the following info:
[image: boot-repair]

**[[ My second attempt ]]**

I create the boot-info of my laptop. I do not know how to read/understand it: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VdZtF7h9XH/

**What do you recommend me to do?**

Comment: What brand/model system? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Are you able to directly boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu?

Comment: @oldfred The laptop is a lenovo legion y 530, with ubuntu 20.04 and windowss 10. It is a i7+ processor, with 8 gb in ram, has 1 tb hd. I do not know how to use ppa. no, I am not able to boot directly from the UEFI (or I am not sure how to do it)

Comment: Instructions on adding ppa to your Ubuntu live installer in link posted above. Your UEFI boot menu is the same menu you use to select USB flash drive to boot. It should also have Windows & Ubuntu entries. See also: Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425907
Lenovo Gamer Legion Y530
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161675/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-load-sdd-nvme-xpg-gammix-lenovo-gamer-legion-y530?noredirect=1#comment1935970_1161675

Comment: @oldfred Yes, from the uefi I can select ubuntu, but, as in the video, when I boot the pc, the boot does not recognise linux boot and continue to the next boot in uefi list, to windows. therefore, I cannot enter to a unix console in order to add a ppa. now, I am going to try enter to a console from installation disk.

Comment: @oldfred This is the boot-info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VdZtF7h9XH/