# Where should I install the bootloader (dual boot with Windows 10) on a laptop with 2 hard drives (SDD + HDD)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, laptop, bootloader

I have a Lenovo Legion Y530 with two hard drives: one is 100GB SDD and the other 1TB HDD.

I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10 2004, so I shrank 75GB of my 1TB HDD and I began installing Ubuntu, but I don't know where to install the bootloader.

Where should I install it, taking into consideration that I will install Ubuntu on the free 75GB of the 1TB HDD ?

[image: disks]

Comment: With UEFI, the options do not work. Ubiquity installer will install Ubuntu/grub's boot files into the first ESP, usually the ESP that Windows already had. If installing to a separate drive, I prefer to have an ESP on that drive also, but use it for backup of the ESP on Windows drive. It can be configured later as boot ESP, but not during install.Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425907
Lenovo Gamer Legion Y530
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161675/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-load-sdd-nvme-xpg-gammix-lenovo-gamer-legion-y530?noredirect=1#comment1935970_1161675

Comment: There is a bug in the Ubuntu installer that prevents putting the bootloader in any drive other than the first, in your case the Windows SSD. You can [get around the bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037843/installing-ubuntu-without-touching-windows) or use the install site by side option (the default) and the installer will automatically put Ubuntu in the free space in the hard drive and the bootloader in the SSD.

Comment: In what mode is Windows installed?  If you'd upgraded from Windows 7, it's likely in legacy mode, so the UEFI installer problems would not apply.  Just ensure you boot the install media in the same mode to install in that mode.

Comment: I would unplug the Windows drive while installing Ubuntu to the other drive. Make sure you install Ubuntu in the same UEFI/BIOS mode as Windows runs in. after the install plug Windows disk back in, boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to the GRUB boot menu.

Comment: Should I install thw bootloader on the efi or Div/Sda?