# GRUB Menu not visible after firmware update on Windows10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, firmware

A few days back, Windows prompted a firmware update, and after the update, my laptop directly boots into Windows10, and GRUB Menu has gone.
To fix this, I changed the boot order in BIOS to Ubuntu first and second Windows. It worked; GRUB Menu appeared like normal.
But after this change, Windows doesn't shut down; it goes to sleep instead. I tried various troubleshooting methods to fix this shutdown, but it didn't work, so I finally restored the boot order, and the GRUB menu disappeared again.
How do I fix this?

Configuration
Dual Boot: Windows10 + Ubuntu18.04
Lenovo LegionY530

Comment: Did you redo all the UEFI settings. Update typically resets UEFI/BIOS to defaults & Windows or Ubuntu update makes its boot loader as first or default boot. Lenovo Gamer Legion Y530
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161675/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-load-sdd-nvme-xpg-gammix-lenovo-gamer-legion-y530?noredirect=1#comment1935970_1161675 & 
Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425907

Comment: No, I just undo the Boot order settings. Okay, so the firmware update probably changed the BIOS settings to default. But, I don't understand is why windows do not shut down when the boot order is changed.  Are any other changes to the settings required while changing the boot order?

Comment: Windows often has to do updates as part of both shutdown & reboot. So you may need to delay power off, so Windows can complete its updates. Do not hibernate if dual booting as that can also cause issues if you want to share a NTFS data partition.