Question about display driver installation on new Lenovo Legion Pro 5i
Planning to install on a Lenovo Legion Pro 5i Gen 8 Intel (16") with RTX™ 4050 (82WK0006US) in a few days. Apparently installing Ubuntu doesn't always go smoothly on this device; I've seen issues with the trackpad (which seem resolvable) as well the sound - but my main concern is the display driver - I gather that PopOs tends to be a better fit, but while I've got one box running Pop, my preference is for straight Ubuntu.
As it happens, Nvidia really isn't a big deal for me, though I probably wouldn't mind getting it to work if it's possible. For now, my priority is just repartitioning and installing and getting it running - my question is, am I better off holding off on the Nvidia installation until I get the thing going, and then seeing how well I can make it work? I've installed Ubuntu enough to know that the easiest way to do this is to indicate I don't want third-party drivers installed; however 1) I don't know if there are other things - like a network card - which would benefit from a third-party driver, and 2) if I do choose NOT to install the Nvidia driver, will Ubuntu use nouveau with the Nvidia, or will it use the onboard Intel UDH driver? Since I'm not much of a gamer, I'm almost indifferent about using the Nvidia - a couple of Java apps I use look like crap with the Nvidia drivers- but I'd at least like to give it a shot

Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available? And if SSD, updated its firmware? From live installer you can check: sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 5 "*-firmware" &
udisksctl status Compare to vendors support page for your model. Some older installs: Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2425907
Lenovo Gamer Legion Y530
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161675/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-load-sdd-nvme-xpg-gammix-lenovo-gamer-legion-y530?noredirect=1#comment1935970_1161675

Installation went as smoothly as could be, was basically up and running in about three hours. First booted up the Windows partition and allowed all the MS s/w and Lenovo firmware updates to complete, then shrunk the partition before booting the thumb drive; might have helped that I downloaded the latest ISO (22.04.4) and did not add the Nvidia (535) driver until after installation.
This Legion Pro 5i (P/N 82WK0006US) replaced a Dell XPS15 that was starting to fail; in this case Aptik performed flawlessly. Not much of a gamer, so lower-spec suits me fine, and for less than $1050 seems to be a pretty good deal.
